# Ignore everything except XmlNodeType.Element

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I must read XML files with `XmlReader`. I am using it like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreComments = true;
settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file, settings);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "NBBOOKS"
            {
                reader.Read();
                nbBooks = int.Parse(reader.Value);
                break;
            }
            case "BOOKS":
            {
                tempReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                while(tempReader.ReadToFollowing("BOOK"))
                {
                    tempReader.ReadToFollowing("TITLE");
                    tempReader.Read();
                    // save title
                    tempReader.ReadToFollowing("SYNOPSIS");
                    tempReader.Read();
                    // save synopsis
                }
                tempReader.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to speed up my application. Therefore, I use `XmlReaderSettings` to ignore comments, processing instructions and whitespace. But my reader still reads `XmlNodeType` other than `XmlNodeType.Element` in (1).

Is there a way to ignore all `XmlNodeType` except `XmlNodeType.Element`?

Answer (score 0):

to Ignore the white spaces you can use this code

```
  _reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
```

then you need for each case for example switch statement

```
 while (reader.Read()) {
       switch (reader.NodeType) {
         case XmlNodeType.Element:
           Console.Write("<{0}>", reader.Name);
           break;
         case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
           Console.Write("<?{0} {1}?>", reader.Name, reader.Value);
           break;
```

and soon on for the rest cases

Comment: I know. I use "if (reader.IsStartElement())" to read only StartElement.
But in (1), there are checks and I want the reader to automatically skip XmlNodeType other than XmlNodeType.Element.